# Ruby on Rails - help needed in writting test cases usinng test:unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit

I am new to Ruby on Rails.
I have created an sample app where I have written test cases using rails test:unit.

Now I am not able to find a way to test my http API calls using test:unit.

### I have two method in my model, one is to GET response from API and another to POST request(JSON data) to API. Here are my methods as follows

class RestApi
  def self.reqSecure(apiMethod, qryString)
    uri = URI.parse("https://test.my-api.com/test.json?apiKey=abc1234&userId=123456")

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)

hashOfResponse = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)
return hashOfResponse
```

end

def self.postSecure
    @host = 'localhost'
    @port = '8099'

```
@path = "/posts"

@body ={
  "bbrequest" => "BBTest",
  "reqid" => "44",
  "data" => {"name" => "test"}
}.to_json

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(@path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
request.body = @body
response = Net::HTTP.new(@host, @port).start {|http| http.request(request) }
puts "Response #{response.code} #{response.message}: #{response.body}"
```

end
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wondering why your test is failing, it might be because the `:new_password` and `:confirm_password` values don't match.

Regarding a good book, I can recommend this one: http://pragprog.com/titles/nrtest/rails-test-prescriptions it covers testing in detail, and is a great resource to learn TDD. I actually used it to learn TDD, and it helped me a lot.

I've since decided to use RSpec and Cucumber for testing, mainly due to 2 other books (http://pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book and http://www.manning.com/katz/).

EDIT:

If you want to test the failing condition, the line after post should be something like

```
assert_nil @user
assert_template :change_password
```

In addition, for clarity's sake, your test name should be something like `test_password_change_failure`.

The last line in your original test shouldn't be there: that's not what your controller is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Actually though my :new_password and :confirm_password are not matching, my test cases are still passing properly. Basically what I want is, I want to test my change_password method for all the if else conditions. given in code and I think my test cases are not compatible with my actual method scenario.